# AWS: redirect elasticbeanstalk.com domain to custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a main domain that point to the amazon elastic beanstalk instance. The url appname.elasticbeanstalk.com is still accessible for public.

Is there a way to add a 301 redirect so that appname.elasticbeanstalk.com points to the main domain that we have registered?

Comment: what language/framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[301 redirect for tomcat](http://nematodes.org/martin/2010/02/04/301-permanent-redirect-with-tomcat-howto/) if you're using it.